# Reference structure within definition - Swift

Tags: swift

```
struct Person {
    var age: Int
    var name: String
    var siblings: Int

    func sameAge(Person: p1, Person: p2) -> Boolean {
        return (p1.age == p2.age)
    }
}
```

How can I reference a **structure** that I'm defining within its own definition, like in the example above?

The error I see is

> Definition conflicts with previous value

Comment: BTW, this function should either be a class function, or it should only take one argument.

Comment: @AaronBrager why is that?

Comment: Because it compares two `Person`s, but there's a third in play: `self`

Comment: Your implementation lets you call `mary.sameAge(p1: john, p2: apollo)` and totally ignores `mary`

Comment: @AaronBrager Got it. Is a class method better than an instance method in any cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter types should go after the colon:

```
func sameAge(p1: Person, _ p2 : Person) -> Boolean {
    return (p1.age == p2.age)
}
```

Comment: oh right...thanks. Do you agree that this should be a class function?

Comment: If you don't use data from the current instance then yes, it makes sense to make function static. Or you could have something like func sameAge(with another: Person) -> Boo {
    return (age == p2.age)
}

Answer (score 0):

You should use a static function or take only one argument as the comment mentioned.

```
func sameAge(p2: Person) -> Boolean {
    return (self.age == p2.age)
}

static func sameAge(p1: Person, p2: Person) -> Boolean {
    return (p1.age == p2.age)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be, but its bad design since you should call `Person.sameAge(p1, p2)` but you're calling `p3.sameAge(p1, p2)` when p3 is not being used.